# Yii2: How to translate a widget that is inside a module

Tags: php, yii2, translation

I currently have a widget inside a module and I would like to create a messages directory so that I can translate module strings from inside that folder.

The issue I have is that I can't get the widget to get the translations from inside the module folder.

This is my structure

```
frontend/modules/comments
frontend/modules/comments/Module.php
frontend/modules/comments/widgets/CommentsWidget.php
frontend/modules/comments/widgets/views/_form.php
```

-Module.php

```
namespace frontend\modules\comments;

use Yii;

class Module extends \yii\base\Module {

    public $controllerNamespace = 'frontend\modules\comments\controllers';

    public function init() {
    parent::init();
    $this->registerTranslations();
    }

    public function registerTranslations() {
    Yii::$app->i18n->translations['modules/comments/*'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
        'sourceLanguage' => 'en',
        'basePath' => '@frontend/modules/comments/messages',
        'fileMap' => [
        'modules/comments/comments' => 'comments.php',
        ]
    ];
    }

    public static function t($category, $message, $params = [], $language = null) {
    return Yii::t('modules/comments/' . $category, $message, $params, $language);
    }

}
```

- _form.php

I use the following code to call the translation.

```
Module::t('comments', 'COMMENT_REPLY')
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Check yii-debug panel, it shows error if can't load translation file or other problems

Answer (score 1):

Have same problem.
It's because you register translations is in init() method (when instance of module was created). You can change registerTranslations() method to static:

```
public function init()
{
    // ...

    self::registerTranslations();
}

public static function registerTranslations()
{
    // ...
}
```

And call it `Content::registerTranslations();` in your widget before use `Module::t()`.